# Batch file - can not read a variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, substitution

Making batch which generate previews (everything is fine with this part of code) and also rename files deleting everything after "_" in filename. For example ABAB_abab.png > ABAB.png
My code does not see a variable yy in the string: set zz=!xx:yy=! Perceives it like just two letters yy, not a variable. How to fix that?

Here is the script

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in ("*.png") do (
    set xx=%%~na
    set yy=_!xx:*_=!
    set zz=!xx:yy=!
    
    echo xx= !xx! @rem (okay, returns ABAB_abab)
    echo yy= !yy! @rem (okay, returns _abab)
    echo zz= !zz! @rem (wrong, returns ABAB_abab without any substitutions)
    pause
    )
endlocal
```

Thank you for help

Comment: It is because `yy` in the xpression `set zz=!xx:yy=!` is taken as a literal string but not a variable reference. Something like `set zz=!xx:!yy!=!` cannot work, because this would try to read variables `!xx:!` and `!=!`. But you can put `!yy!` into a `for` meta-variable, which can be nested within `!!`: `for %%y in ("!yy!") do set "zz=!xx:_%%~y=!"` (note that I also included the leading `_` in the search string since you want ot removed). Take a look at this related thread: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10166386)…

Comment: Thank your explanation. I put this part: [code] for %%y in ("!yy!") do set "zz=!xx:_%%~y=!" [code] and now it see the variable yy. Bud lost a variable xx. So result is xx:__abab. What else I can change?

Comment: Oh, I think I oversaw the fact that you already placed the leading `_` to the assignment of `yy`, so it should read `set "zz=!xx:%%~y=!"`. However, this does (still) not touch the variable `xx`. Anyway, you could even simplify the approach: `for %%y in ("_!xx:*_=!") do set "zz=!xx:%%~y=!"` (there is no more variable `yy`)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example to show you a method of achieving another layer of expansion:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For %%G In ("*.png") Do (
    Set "xx=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "yy=_!xx:*_=!"
    For %%H In ("!yy!") Do Set "zz=!xx:%%~H=!"
    Echo xx = "!xx!"
    Echo yy = "!yy!"
    Echo zz = "!zz!"
    EndLocal
    Pause
)
```

The doublequotes are included in the `Echo` commands only for better visualization should there be any spaces in your strings, they're not needed for any other purpose.

*Please note, that this will not achieve your intention with any `.png` files whose basename begins with one or more underscores, `_`.*